# A challenging horizontal/vertical centering problem

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I need a box that typesets a kind of compass in a square.
It should look like this figure

```
 +-----------------+
 |        N        |
 |                 |
 |                 |
 | W      X      E |
 |                 |
 |                 |
 |        S        |
 +-----------------+
```

The requirements

1) The N and S should be horizontally centered with respect to the left/right side of the frame and at say 0.3em from the top/lower side of the frame.

2) The W and E should be vertically centered with respect to the top/lower side of the frame and at say 0.3em from the left/right side of the frame.

3) The middle of X (normally a 1 or 2 digit number) should be on the crosspoint of the (hor.) midline through W and E AND the (vert.) midline through N and S.

4) enlarging the font size should equally (well more or less) enlarge the compass size, as well as the thickness of the frame. This should work from 'tiny' upto 'HUGE' and also when 'scalefont' is used to change the font size.

5) Important is that the centering (hor. and vert.) is maintained when the size changes.

I tried several implementations, e.g. using a tabular or using raiseboxes.
But every time I got stuck with the vertical alignment.

Does someone know how to do this?

BTW: Requirement 3 is not a mathematical one. It should just look like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Picture mode!

The side of the square is 5em, because `\unitlength` is set to 1em (which will take into account the current font). Therefore 0.3 represents a distance of 0.3em, which is what you seem to want. Fix the size according to your taste.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\newcommand{\compass}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength\unitlength{1em}%
  \linethickness{0.2ex}%
  \begin{picture}(5,5)
  % the frame
  \moveto(0,0)\lineto(0,5)\lineto(5,5)\lineto(5,0)\closepath\strokepath
  % the cardinal points
  \put(2.5,4.7){\makebox[0pt]{\raisebox{-\height}{N}}}
  \put(2.5,0.3){\makebox[0pt]{S}}
  \put(0.3,2.5){\makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{W}}}
  \put(4.7,2.5){\makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{E}}}
  % the center
  \put(2.5,2.5){\makebox(0,0){#1}}
  \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

X\compass{1}X\qquad{\footnotesize X\compass{3}X}\qquad{\tiny X\compass{5}X}

\bigskip

{\Large X\compass{12}X}\qquad{\Huge X\compass{24}X}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Was thinking whether I should use `picture` but decided against it. Btw. you're missing the thickening of the surrounding line it seems.

Comment: @Skillmon Done!

Comment: Then it's a +1.

Comment: Can you explain how to get the magic constants (2.5, 4.7, 0.3) (e.g. what they represent)?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR 2.5 is half of 5 -> the middle. 4.7 is 0.3 less than 5 -> 0.3 from border. And the unit of measurement is set to 1em with `\setlength\unitlength{1em}`. 5 is the width and height because of the `\polyline` command's arguments.

Comment: How would you take care of the spacing between the W and the frame? It looks to be positioned slightly more towards the middle (in all the solutions, btw) and more separated from the frame than the other letters because of its different width. How could we account for that?

Comment: @thymaro the distance of the box around the W is the same in all posts and is 0.3em. TeX doesn't know how much of the box is white space and how much is actually a glyph. I think it would be better to fix the distance between the border and the middle of the glyphs instead of the distance between border of glyph box and border of compass. That could lead to a more balanced look, but wasn't requested by OP.

Comment: Could some kind soul explain the (0,2) as last argument of the polyline? It looks unnecesary. But if I remove it then in the left lower corner the frame(line) doesn't fit.

Comment: @Jack There's no “closepath” for `\polyline`. I modified the code so an additional segment is not needed.

Comment: @Skillmon: Indeed I did not requested the "more balanced look". But still I am interested to see the code AND the result.

Comment: @Jack I don't think you can get a “more balanced look” in any way: if you move left the “E” so its center has the same distance from the frame as the center of the “W”, the hole will be very evident and produce an unbalanced look. You might use sans serif mono font, maybe, for the cardinal points, but then also the number in the center should be in the same font.

Comment: @Jack see the edit to my answer. egreg is right though, it doesn't look as good as I thought.

Comment: First, thanks to all for helping me.

@Skillmon: I didn't mention the fact that X could be smaller, but in fact it will be. So thanks for taking that in account too. But...
in your 2nd 'wild mix' version the EW line is _not_ vertically centered as
stated in R2, whereas in your 1st version it is. If you enlarge the diagram
it becomes visible.

And yes, the tikz solutions _are_ an overkill and I won't use tikz.
Nevertheless they are 'simple' implementations, showing what smart things
can be done with tikz.

Comment: In egregs solution one can easily make the  'X' smaller. Additionally it is
easy to have different vertical/horizontal offsets to the frame. So I will
accept his solution.

There remains one issue though: In my real application
the compass size is 2.5em, not 5em. This makes the letters far more
prominent and thus more unbalanced than in the examples shown. Even when
there is no 'X' in the middle. I guess I have to live with that.

Comment: I don't even need this and I want to use it! Was searching on how to draw a box with `pict2e` , and this gave me an idea for an even better solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The following is a wild mix between LaTeX stuff and stuff you'd do using plain TeX. Change the default value of the optional argument of `\compass` to change the overall size. The overall size is not equal to the optional argument, but to `#1+.6em+.4ex` in width, `#1+.3em+.2ex` in height and `.3em+.2ex` in depth.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

% this might already be defined depending on included packages
\providecommand\clap[1]{\hbox to 0pt{\hss #1\hss}}

\newcommand\compass[2][10ex]
  {{%
    \fboxrule=.2ex
    \fboxsep=.3em
    \fbox
      {%
        \vbox to #1{\hsize=#1
          \hbox to #1{\hss N\hss}%
          \vss
          \hbox to #1{\rlap{W}\hss \clap{#2}\hss \llap{E}}%
          \vss
          \hbox to #1{\hss S\hss}%
        }%
      }%
  }}

\begin{document}
\compass{1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Vertically it only aligns the baselines of `W x E` so if `x` is recognizable smaller than `W` and `E` it would not look vertically centred.

Version that also vertically centres the middle line using `$\vcenter{...}$` (and utilizing that the `\xlap` macros use a `\hbox` internally so the text is not typeset in math mode):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

% this might already be defined depending on included packages
\providecommand\clap[1]{\hbox to 0pt{\hss #1\hss}}

\newcommand\compass[2][10ex]
  {{%
    \fboxrule=.2ex
    \fboxsep=.3em
    \fbox
      {%
        \vbox to #1{\hsize=#1
          \hbox to #1{\hss N\hss}%
          \vss
          \hbox to #1{%
            $\vcenter{\rlap{W}}$\hss
            $\vcenter{\clap{#2}}$\hss
            $\vcenter{\llap{E}}$%
          }%
          \vss
          \hbox to #1{\hss S\hss}%
        }%
      }%
  }}

\begin{document}
\compass{\tiny1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Version that gives the same distance from the centre of the W and E to the border. Unfortunately it doesn't look as good as I thought.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

% this might already be defined depending on included packages
\providecommand\clap[1]{\hbox to 0pt{\hss #1\hss}}

\newbox\myTestbox
\newdimen\myhoffset
\newcommand\compass[2][10ex]
  {{%
    \setbox\myTestbox\hbox{E}%
    \myhoffset=.5\wd\myTestbox
    \setbox\myTestbox\hbox{W}%
    \ifdim\myhoffset<.5\wd\myTestbox
      \myhoffset=.5\wd\myTestbox
    \fi
    \fboxrule=.2ex
    \fboxsep=.3em
    \fbox
      {%
        \vbox to #1{\hsize=#1
          \hbox to #1{\hss N\hss}%
          \vss
          \hbox to #1{%
            \hskip\myhoffset
            $\vcenter{\clap{W}}$\hss
            $\vcenter{\clap{#2}}$\hss
            $\vcenter{\clap{E}}$%
            \hskip\myhoffset
          }%
          \vss
          \hbox to #1{\hss S\hss}%
        }%
      }%
  }}

\begin{document}
\compass[8ex]{\tiny1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As OP noted, the `\vcenter` code has a small vertical offset from the middle. Therefore here another version, this time using some `\smash`s and a calculated `\raise` amount for `#2`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

% this might already be defined depending on included packages
\providecommand\clap[1]{\hbox to 0pt{\hss #1\hss}}

\newdimen\myvoffset
\newbox\mytestboxA
\newbox\mytestboxB
\newcommand\compass[2][10ex]
  {{%
    \setbox\mytestboxA\hbox{WE}%
    \setbox\mytestboxB\hbox{#2}%
    \myvoffset=\dimexpr
      \ht\mytestboxA-\ht\mytestboxB+\dp\mytestboxB-\dp\mytestboxA\relax
    \myvoffset=.5\myvoffset
    \fboxrule=.2ex
    \fboxsep=.3em
    \fbox
      {%
        \vbox to #1{\hsize=#1
          \hbox to #1{\hss N\hss}%
          \vss
          \hbox to #1{%
            \smash{\rlap{W}}\hss
            \smash{\clap{\raise\myvoffset\hbox{#2}}}\hss
            \smash{\llap{E}}%
          }%
          \vss
          \hbox to #1{\hss S\hss}%
        }%
      }%
  }}

\begin{document}
\compass[2.5em]{\tiny1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness (as this is overkill for the problem) a Ti*k*Z based answer (you'll need `\usepackage{tikz}` in your preamble). The optional argument matches the size

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\newcommand\compass[2][15ex]
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
      \draw[line width=.2ex,use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#1);
      \node at (0.5*#1,0.5*#1) {#2};
      \node[anchor=north] at (0.5*#1,#1-0.3em) {N};
      \node[anchor=south] at (0.5*#1,0.3em) {S};
      \node[anchor=west] at (0.3em,0.5*#1) {W};
      \node[anchor=east] at (#1-0.3em,0.5*#1) {E};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{document}
\compass{\tiny1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Tikz version

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\compass[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em,y=1em]
    \coordinate (SW);
    \draw[line width=0.1em] (SW) rectangle +(6,6)coordinate(NE);
    \coordinate (Mid) at ($(SW)!0.5!(NE)$);
    \node[inner sep=0.3em,anchor=west] at (Mid -| SW) {W};
    \node[inner sep=0.3em,anchor=east] at (Mid -| NE) {E};
    \node[inner sep=0.3em,anchor=south] at (Mid |- SW) {S};
    \node[inner sep=0.3em,anchor=north] at (Mid |- NE) {N};
    \node[inner sep=0.3em] at (Mid) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
A\compass{12}A%
\Huge A\compass{12}A%
\footnotesize A\compass{12}A
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you use `\MyAht` instead of a unit like `1ex` or `1em`?

Comment: @Skillmon, Yes, that is better. I have updated. Quite close to your solution. Didn't see that until now.

Comment: I honestly think yours is better. Instead of using the inner sep to get the distances I calculate the reference point and set inner sep to 0pt. Yours is cleverer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice usecase for the `xcoffins` package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\NewCoffin\CompassCoffin
\NewCoffin\NorthCoffin
\NewCoffin\SouthCoffin
\NewCoffin\EastCoffin
\NewCoffin\WestCoffin
\NewCoffin\CenterCoffin
\newcommand\compass[1][10ex]{%
  \begingroup
    \SetHorizontalCoffin\NorthCoffin{N}%
    \SetHorizontalCoffin\SouthCoffin{S}%
    \SetHorizontalCoffin\EastCoffin{E}%
    \SetHorizontalCoffin\WestCoffin{W}%
    \SetHorizontalCoffin\CenterCoffin{$+$}%
    \SetVerticalCoffin\CompassCoffin{#1}{%
      \vbox to #1{%
        \hfil\vfil
      }%
    }%
    % Add the north at the *t*op, *h*orizontal *c*enter
    \JoinCoffins
      \CompassCoffin[t,hc]
      \NorthCoffin[t,hc]%
    % Add the east at the *v*ertical *c*enter, *r*ight
    \JoinCoffins
      \CompassCoffin[vc,r]
      \EastCoffin[vc,r]%
    % Add the south at the *b*ottom, *h*orizontal *c*enter
    \JoinCoffins
      \CompassCoffin[b,hc]
      \SouthCoffin[b,hc]%
    % Add the west at the *v*ertical *c*enter, *l*eft
    \JoinCoffins
      \CompassCoffin[vc,l]
      \WestCoffin[vc,l]%
    % Add the center at the *v*ertical *c*enter, *h*orizontal *c*enter
    \JoinCoffins
      \CompassCoffin[vc,hc]
      \CenterCoffin[vc,hc]%
    \setlength\fboxrule{.2ex}%
    \setlength\fboxsep{.3em}%
    \fbox{\TypesetCoffin\CompassCoffin}%
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\noindent\compass\\
\large\compass\\
\footnotesize\compass
\end{document}
```

[image]